# Execute task after reaching threshold for maximumRedeliveries in Camel

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have implemented a retry functionality in my code using camel retry. It will  retry a maximum of five times.

```
onException(Exception.class)
    .maximumRedeliveries(5)
    .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
    .backOffMultiplier(5)
    .maximumRedeliveryDelay(5)
    .useExponentialBackOff();
```

Now I want to call a custom method if the threshold has been reached instead of throwing an exception. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `handled-flag`to true and then call your custom bean.

```
onException(Exception.class)
    .maximumRedeliveries(5)
    .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
    .backOffMultiplier(5)
    .maximumRedeliveryDelay(5)
    .useExponentialBackOff()
    .handled(true)
    .to("bean:myCustomBean");
```

Answer (score 2):

This is exact use-case for [Dead Letter Channel EIP pattern](http://camel.apache.org/dead-letter-channel.html). I would suggest converting your `onException` block to `errorHandler` and use `deadLetterChannel` builder.

```
errorHandler(
        deadLetterChannel("direct:redeliveryExhausted")
                .maximumRedeliveries(5)
                .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
                .backOffMultiplier(5)
                .maximumRedeliveryDelay(5)
                .useExponentialBackOff()
);

from("direct:redeliveryExhausted")
        .log("I am going to handle non-deliverable message")
        .log("Because of this exception: ${exception}")
        .to("log:failed");
```